# Правильное написание

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли написано предложение: «в конечном итоге в процессе обучения обучаемые должны приобрести комплекс знаний, умений и навыков, необходимых для использования учетной документации в качестве важного профессионального качества»?

Comment: В то же время проведение ТСЗ с совершением 250 км марша показали,  с какой активностью, заинтересованностью участвуют в них курсанты, приобретаются навыки «военного водителя». 
Повышение качества подготовки специалистов в наших организациях зависит от многих факторов: 
- эффективности организации образовательного процесса (наличия совершенной учебно-материальной базы); 
уровня подготовки преподавателей, инструкторов по вождению автомобилей  и учебно – методической работы с ними;


Comment: Очень интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Стилистически - очень плохо.
"В качестве важного качества" - ни в какие ворота не лезет. Да и "конечный итог" вкупе с "(в процессе) обучения обучаемые" - тоже не здорово. Я даже не рискую предлагать вариант правки, настолько всё туманно. Попробуйте все нормальным языком сказать, без канцелярщины.
Как-то так: "Конечная цель обучения - приобретение учащимися навыков профессионального использования учетной документации".